# I cannot run the watchTask using Gulp

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I'm setting up a development using node.js and gulp. which consists of functions like `scssTask`, `jsTask`, `cacheBustTask`, `watchTask`. and a `default` task.

This error occurs when running gulp in terminal:
`ReferenceError: watch is not defined`

https://www.screencast.com/t/ercavfT2gZb

Comment: You will have to include your gulpfile.js in your question, particularly the `watch` task part.  You should also include the text - not an image - of your error.  I have made that edit for you.  Otherwise it cannot be found with a search.

Comment: This is the gulp.js file see here https://www.screencast.com/t/PXi6o2ECgENT

Comment: Please edit your question to add the entire gulpfile.js code.  As is, it isn't much help to anyone who might come here in the future - and the screencast link will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You call `watch` in your `watchTask` but that is never defined because you didn't include it in the `require` statement.

```
const { src, dest, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
```

Add `watch` to that:

```
const { src, dest, series, parallel, watch } = require('gulp');
```